# Почему не работает iAd в iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, iphone, монетизация

1. Создал проект `Single View Application`,
2. Добавил `iAd framework` в проект,
3. сделал `import iAd` в ViewController.swift,
4. Добавил `ADBannerView` на контроллер в storyboard,
5. Связал вьюху с аутлетом,
6. `ViewController` обозвал делегатом баннера,
7. Указал, что `ViewController: UIViewController, ADBannerViewDelegate`

запускаю проект и все время ловлю ошибку

> Error Domain = ADErrorDomain Code = 4 "Application has iAd Network
>   configuration error"  UserInfo = { ADInternalErrorCode = 4,
>   NSLocalizedFailureReason = Application has iAd Network configuration
>   error, ADInternalErrorDomain = ADErrorDomain}

Могу ли я без аккаунта разработчика делать такие тестовые приложения, или я должен настроить показ iAd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что `iAd` закрыты с 30 июня. [Ссылка на официальную новость](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=01152016a)

Используйте другие рекламные площадки. К примеру, [admob](https://www.google.com/admob/)

Comment: а они навсегда закрывают, или переделают и потом вновь дадут возможность использовать?

Comment: @DotProx судя по формулировке, навсегда. Но может выкатят позже что-то другое, кто их знает. А если и выкатят, то уверен, что многие моменты будут изменены.